# What's the video game in the movie "Big"

Tags: game-identification

In the movie Big (starring Tom Hanks), he plays a video game involving a wizard on a couple of occasions:

[image: Picture of scene from movie]

What game is it? Is it just a fake game made up for the movie?

Comment: Always wondered this. Thought it must have been an early Kings Quest or something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[According to Destructoid](http://www.destructoid.com/play-the-computer-game-seen-in-the-movie-big-152328.phtml), it is not a real game.

> At the time, the game looked awesome and I really wanted to play it but, sadly, the game never actually existed

However, there is a Flash game linked in that article that resembles the game from *Big*.

> Twenty years later, BoMToons has sought to [remedy this situation](http://bomtoons.com/viewcomments.php?id=31) by creating a little Flash game which very closely resembles the one seen in the film. There isn't a whole lot to it, as there was very little to work with from the source material (which consists of one room in a cave and one text command entered). The game, called The Cavern of the Evil Wizard, takes place entirely in that one room and is solved in exactly the same manner as in the film, but there are a few other commands in the text parser that you can play around with.

Answer (score -1):

No the game is not made up it is called Cavern of the Evil Wizard.

Comment: It seems as if Michael Herold's answer is more complete than yours? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Interesting, could you provide more details or a link?

Comment: It's not the game is made up, it technically exists, but the game that does exist was based off the game seen in the movie (which is what the other answer basically says).